# Button result not as desired

Tags: css, ipad, safari

Why is it that when I test my page out on Chrome Canary emulating the iPad I get this result,

[image]

But when testing it out on the real device I get this 
[image]

I'm trying to achieve the top one, but can't for some reason. Any ideas? Also is Chrome Canary reliable? Here's the CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
background: #fff;
color: #7b8993;
font: 300 87.5%/1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.form-wrapper {
padding-top: 10%;
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 50px auto;
position: relative;
width: 375px;
}

form {
padding: 30px 20px 0;
}

.form-item {
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
}

.form-item input {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #000;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
height: 50px;
padding: 0 16px;
transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
}

.form-item input:focus {
outline: none;
border-color: #9ecaed;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}

.button-panel {
margin: 20px 0 0;
width: 100%;
}

.button-panel .button {
background: #009dff;
border: none;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
height: 50px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
letter-spacing: 0.05em;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
}

.button:hover {
background: #00c8ff;
}

@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
.form-wrapper {
padding-top: 10%;
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 50px auto;
position: relative;
width: 320px;
}
}


.cent {
text-align: center;
color: #000;
}

.view {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #7b8993;
padding-top: 5px;
}

#ref {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #7b8993;
padding-top: 8px;
font-size: 16px;
}

#ref:hover {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #009dff;
-webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
padding-top: 8px;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following to the `button` element in order to remove the default styling.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```